# GridView rendered very long time with HTTP response

Tags: android, http, listview

I'm beginner in Android development. I'm using this library for http requests https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http.

And then I render response JSON in GridView it takes very long time. I'm using progress dialog as preloader, but it's removed before listview is rendered. How I can solve this problem? Thank you.

Here is screenshot of this GridView.

[image]

Here is implementation of this activity.

```
public class LikesActivity extends BottomBarActivity //some custom activity {
List<Anticafe> mAnticafes = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_likes);

        /*some code*/



        Request.post(Constants.POST_SEARCH_API_LINK, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    Request request = gson.fromJson(new String(responseBody), Request.class);

                    mAnticafes = request.getAnticafes();
                    renderListView()
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    hideProcessDialog();
                }
            });


    }

    private void renderListView() {
         GridView likesList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.likes_list);
        AnticafeAdapter anticafeAdapter = new AnticafeAdapter(this, mAnticafes); 
        anticafeAdapter.setWidth(getWidth());
        likesList.setAdapter(anticafeAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is full implementaion of adapter.

```
public class AnticafeAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public static final String TAG = "image-request";
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Anticafe> mAnticafes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Client mClient;
    private View mConvertView;
    private int mWidth;

    public AnticafeAdapter(Context context, List<Anticafe> anticafes) {
        mContext = context;
        mAnticafes = anticafes;
    }

    public void setWidth(int mWidth) {
        this.mWidth = (int) (mWidth / 4.7);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mAnticafes.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Anticafe getItem(int position) {
        return mAnticafes.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).getId();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final Anticafe anticafe = getItem(position);
        mClient = AnticafeApplication.getInstanse().getClient();
        mConvertView = convertView;
        final ProgressDialog processDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        processDialog.setMessage("Информация обновляется. Пожалуйста, подождите.");

        if(mConvertView == null) {
            mConvertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adapter_popular, null);
        }

        ImageView cover = (ImageView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.cover);
        CircularImageView logo = (CircularImageView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        final ImageView like = (ImageView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.like);
        final TextView likesCount = (TextView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.likes_count);
        TextView name = (TextView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView price = (TextView) mConvertView.findViewById(R.id.price);

        if(mClient != null) {
            final boolean liked = mClient.containsLike(anticafe.getId());
            if(liked) {
                like.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_like));
            } else {
                like.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_unlike));
            }
        } else {
            like.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_unlike));
        }

        likesCount.setText(String.valueOf(anticafe.getTotalLikes()));
        name.setText(anticafe.getName());
        price.setText(anticafe.getPrices());

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(anticafe.getAttachment().getCover()).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(cover);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(anticafe.getAttachment().getLogo()).resize(mWidth, mWidth).into(logo);

        likeMechanism(anticafe, processDialog, like, likesCount);

        name.setOnClickListener(anticafeOpenActivityEvent(anticafe.getId()));
        price.setOnClickListener(anticafeOpenActivityEvent(anticafe.getId()));
        logo.setOnClickListener(anticafeOpenActivityEvent(anticafe.getId()));
        cover.setOnClickListener(anticafeOpenActivityEvent(anticafe.getId()));

        BottomBarActivity activity = (BottomBarActivity) this.mContext;
        activity.hideProcessDialog();

        return mConvertView;
    }

    private void likeMechanism(final Anticafe anticafe, final ProgressDialog processDialog, final ImageView like, final TextView likesCount) {
        like.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (mClient == null) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                    builder.setTitle("Вы не авторизованы")
                            .setMessage("До тех пор, пока вы не пройдете авторизацию, вы не сможете пользоваться некоторым функционалом нашего приложение. Авторизация займет всего лишь пару минут.")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Скрыть", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton("Авторизоваться", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AuthActivity.class);
                                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                                    Activity activity = ((Activity) mContext);
                                    activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_in_right);
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();

                } else {

                    processDialog.show();

                    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                    params.add("anticafe_id", anticafe.getId() + "");
                    AuthedRequest.post(Constants.LIKE_API_LINK, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                            processDialog.hide();
                            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                            try {
                                LikeResponse response = gson.fromJson(new String(responseBody, Constants.UTF_8), LikeResponse.class);
                                if (response.getLikeStatus().equals("unliked")) {
                                    like.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_unlike));
                                } else if (response.getLikeStatus().equals("liked")) {
                                    like.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_like));
                                }
                                likesCount.setText(String.valueOf(response.getTotalLikes()));
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                processDialog.hide();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                            try {
                                Log.d("json", "onSuccess: " + new String(responseBody, Constants.UTF_8));
                            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                processDialog.hide();
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private OnClickListener anticafeOpenActivityEvent(final int id) {
        return new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("entity_id", id);
                ((BottomBarActivity) mContext).openNewActivity(AnticafeActivity.class, bundle);
            }
        };
    }

    private static class LikeResponse {

        @SerializedName("status")
        @Expose
        private Integer status;
        @SerializedName("error")
        @Expose
        private Boolean error;
        @SerializedName("likeStatus")
        @Expose
        private String likeStatus;
        @SerializedName("totalLikes")
        @Expose
        private Integer totalLikes;

        public LikeResponse(Integer status, Boolean error, String likeStatus, Integer totalLikes) {
            this.status = status;
            this.error = error;
            this.likeStatus = likeStatus;
            this.totalLikes = totalLikes;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The status
         */
        public Integer getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param status
         * The status
         */
        public void setStatus(Integer status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The error
         */
        public Boolean getError() {
            return error;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param error
         * The error
         */
        public void setError(Boolean error) {
            this.error = error;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The likeStatus
         */
        public String getLikeStatus() {
            return likeStatus;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param likeStatus
         * The likeStatus
         */
        public void setLikeStatus(String likeStatus) {
            this.likeStatus = likeStatus;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         * The totalLikes
         */
        public Integer getTotalLikes() {
            return totalLikes;
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param totalLikes
         * The totalLikes
         */
        public void setTotalLikes(Integer totalLikes) {
            this.totalLikes = totalLikes;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont show any code to say exactly what is you problem.
But any way its better to use a third party library for loading images from web such as picasso:
http://square.github.io/picasso
this library load your images smoothly and mange caches by itself.
**UPDATE:**
Other option is that you dont use viewHolder design pattern in your getView method in your adapter class.
In your current code you call findViewById method in every cell of your gridView but you must call it only first time.
to resolve this problem you should use viewHolder design pattern.

An exampple of getView method with view Holder :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    /*
     * The convertView argument is essentially a "ScrapView" as described is Lucas post 
     * http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/
     * It will have a non-null value when ListView is asking you recycle the row layout. 
     * So, when convertView is not null, you should simply update its contents instead of inflating a new row layout.
     */
    if(convertView==null){

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);

        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // object item based on the position
    ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];

    // assign values if the object is not null
    if(objectItem != null) {
        // get the TextView from the ViewHolder and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setText(objectItem.itemName);
        viewHolder.textViewItem.setTag(objectItem.itemId);
    }

    return convertView;

}
```

Example of View holder class (define your view elements in this class) :

```
static class ViewHolderItem {
    TextView textViewItem;
}
```

for more info see this :
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

Comment: Ok i think understand your problem

Comment: Thank you, y.feizi !) You are realy help me!)